# Process data per group in Hive with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, group-by, hive, pyspark

I have some user data stored in a Hive table (ORC file format) with multiple rows per user. For example:

```
user | attr1 | attr2
---- | ----- | -----
u1   | 1     | a
u1   | 2     | b
u2   | 3     | a
u2   | 4     | b
```

I need to map each group of rows belonging to the same user to compute some string. In this example, `f([(1, a), (2, b)])` and `f([(3, a), (4, b)])`.

How can this be done using Hive + Spark's Python API?

From what I could see the Python `GroupedData` API have only stat functions. Should I resort to reducing the underlying Rows RDD? Is there a more efficient manner that makes use of the Hive/ORC columnar format for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([['u1', 1, 'a'], ['u1', 2, 'b'], ['u2', 3, 'a'], ['u2', 4, 'b']],
                           schema=['user', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df = df.groupBy('user').agg(f.collect_list(f.array(df['attr1'], df['attr2'])).alias('array_col'))
df = df.withColumn('len_col', f.size(df['new_col']))
df.show(truncate=False)

+----+----------------------------------------+-------+                         
|user|array_col                               |len_col|
+----+----------------------------------------+-------+
|u1  |[WrappedArray(1, a), WrappedArray(2, b)]|2      |
|u2  |[WrappedArray(3, a), WrappedArray(4, b)]|2      |
+----+----------------------------------------+-------+
```